# How to @Autowired a List<Integer> in spring framework

Tags: java, spring, autowired, spring-java-config

I have a configuration class as below:

```
@Configuration
public class ListConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public List<Integer> list() {
        List<Integer> ints = new ArrayList<>();
        ints.add(1);
        ints.add(2);
        ints.add(3);
        return ints;
    }

    @Bean
    public int number() {
        return 4;
    }
}
```

I also have a test class as below

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = ListConfiguration.class)
public class ListTest {
    @Autowired
    List<Integer> ints;

    @Test
    public void print() {
        System.out.println(ints.size());
        System.out.println(ints);
    }
}
```

But the output of the `print` method is `1` and `[4]`, why not `3` and `[1,2,3]`? Thank you very much for any help!

Comment: can you show your `applicationContext.xml` please?

Comment: Is there any reason you wouldn't be using `@Value`?

Comment: @AbbasKararawala I use java config, not xml config. The `ListConfiguration` is the configuration class.

Comment: @JamesENL This is just a demo code. I just want to get a bean with type List<Integer>.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You've got a bean of type `Integer` and a bean of type `List<Integer>` in your application context.

Now obviously the bean you want to autowire is of type `List<Integer>`, which does qualify as a candidate for autowiring. To discover how Spring actually autowires fields I had to dive deep into the `AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor` class.

TL;DR of my investigation is that Spring will prefer to autowire objects in the following order:

1. Default Value using `@Value`
2. Multiple beans using a type parameter.
3. Individual beans that match the field type.

That means that if you're autowiring a `List<Integer>` Spring will attempt to autowire multiple `Integer` beans into the list before it will attempt to autowire a single `List<Integer>` bean.

You can see this behaviour in the `DefaultListableBeanFactory` class.

Relevant snippet below:

```
public Object doResolveDependency(DependencyDescriptor descriptor, String beanName,
        Set<String> autowiredBeanNames, TypeConverter typeConverter) throws BeansException {

    Class<?> type = descriptor.getDependencyType();
    //Searches for an @Value annotation and 
    Object value = getAutowireCandidateResolver().getSuggestedValue(descriptor);
    if (value != null) {
        //Handle finding, building and returning default value
    }
    /* 
     * Check for multiple beans of given type. Because a bean is returned here,
     * Spring autowires the Integer bean instance.
     */
    Object multipleBeans = resolveMultipleBeans(descriptor, beanName, autowiredBeanNames, typeConverter);
    if (multipleBeans != null) {
        return multipleBeans;
    }
    InjectionPoint previousInjectionPoint = ConstructorResolver.setCurrentInjectionPoint(descriptor);
    try {
        Map<String, Object> matchingBeans = findAutowireCandidates(beanName, type, descriptor);
        // Do more stuff here to try and narrow down to a single instance to autowire.
    }
}
```

Hopefully this explains why you do need to use an `@Qualifer` annotation when trying to autowire a list of a type when you've got individual beans of that type in your application context.

**EDIT:**
It's worth noting that this is not good practice. Creating a collection of primitives or primitive wrappers and registering it as a bean is going to cause issues. The best way to do this is with `@Value` and define your list of primitives in a properties file, that Spring picks up.

Example:

application.properties file

```
list=1,2,3,4
```

In your config class declare the following bean:

```
@Bean 
public ConversionService conversionService() {
    return new DefaultConversionService();
}
```

The default conversion service is used to convert comma separated values declared in a properties file into a collection of objects with type safety.

Class to use it:

```
@Value("${list}")
private List<Integer> anotherList;
```

`anotherList` will contain 1,2,3 & 4 as elements in the list.

Comment: Do you agree that considering special Spring autowiring rules for collections best practice is NOT register collections as beans? For example my application used collection beans and after https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-13963 my application does not work.

Comment: Oh absolutely! If you're trying to autowire a collection of primitives or primitive wrappers you're doing something wrong. I have an array of String's coming from a properties file that I use `@Value` for, but I'd never create a bean to hold my array.

Answer (score 1):

May be Spring is injecting all the `Integer` type beans into a `List` instead of Autowiring `List<Integer>` bean that you declared.

Probably if you add `@Qualifier("list")` at your injection point in your Test then it will provide the behavior you are expecting.